# ArcHydro flood depth artifacts

Tags: arc-hydro

I'm trying to delineate floodplains in a catchment using "Stream WSE from point WSE Measurements" as in (https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/03/17/floodplain-delineation-using-only-arc-hydro-models) but I got strange artifacts in the resulting flood depth raster (in the areas outlined with the rectangles, the orange line is the river center line):

[image]

In the biggest rectangle at the bottom of the image, the depth between each side of the "breaking line" rises sharply of 8 meters. I don't really understand because the underling DEM is smooth at this location with only a difference of 1 meter.

Any idea from where this kind of artifacts could come from?